# pfSense Ldap Group Authentication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, pfsense, groups

I have been battling with this for 3 days now and it's driving me a little crazy.

I can authenticate via user using Ldap using the following search filter:
sAMAccountName=%s

I cannot seem to get this done with a group however... I have tried the following search filters:

- (&(memberOf=cn=ProxyAccess,ou=pfsense,dc=MyDomain,dc=local)(sAMAccountName=%s))
- (&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=ProxyAccess,ou=pfsense,dc=MyDomain,dc=local)(sAMAccountName=%s))

Whilst trying to authenticate, I run tail -f cache.log and I cannot see any errors

Can anyone please assist me?

Is there also a way getting more detailed  logging so I can try figure out what is going on?

I am assuming it is the search filter as I can authenticate when just using the user search filter

Your assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) to test those filters?